# jquery validate plugin highlight error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two text boxes within an td (td is the parent). My validation highlight is:

```
  unhighlight: function(element) {
  $(element).parent().removeClass('error');
```

And my css is:

```
.error {background-color:#F00;}
```

Both are required to be not null.

When both are invalid, the td element goes red. But when one is valid and the other not, the td goes white.

How can I fix this so that if at least one textbox is invalid, the whole td element is highlighted?

Comment: will you post your full jquery code..

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the other text box (element) before removing the 'error' class. Assuming your text box is an input, a small example to test if there is a text inside the sibling element, will look like this:

```
unhighlight: function(element) {
    if ($(element).siblings('input').val() != '') {
        $(element).parent().removeClass('error');
    }
}
```